# "observer" or "supervisor" or "overseer" computer

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I'm a little confused about the usage of "observer" vs "supervisor" vs "overseer". Imagine we have two computers or two systems. Computer1 controls the computer2 and checks to see whether it is not performing so many tasks at the same time. Computer2 informs its state to computer1 and etc.

Here what is the role of computer1? Is it 'observer' or 'supervisor' or 'overseer' of the computer2?

Comment: An automatic system, whether a software or hardware component, or dedicated system, that controls the operations of another, is often called a *manager* or *controller*. The term *supervisor* is less commonly used, usually to describe a software component that launches services for an operating system. The terms *observer* and *monitor* describe a system that queries and records the status of another, without affecting its operation. (The term *overseer* is not used in any such context.)

Answer (score 1):

The controller computer or the controlling computer.

In short, the controller, after it has been mentioned once.

[controller](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTLNcnFZyxsn3u-ToO2ABlBs1Ycaw%3A1578002835664&ei=k2kOXp6eKOWm_Qam1pDIAg&q=%22the%20controller%20computer%22&oq=%22the%20controller%20computer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l3.18794.23309..23593...1.0..3.447.5137.4j16j7j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i302i39j35i39j0i273j0j0i67.eYlFLQYf4fc&ved=0ahUKEwjes-XT9uXmAhVlU98KHSYrBCkQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

[controlling](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTLTRKBhgGG_eZ8s6rC-5Hr63mFGA%3A1578002860382&ei=rGkOXrryFuu3ggfkw434Bg&q=%22the%20controlling%20computer%22&oq=%22the%20controlling%20computer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30j0i30j0i8i30l5.21215.21917..22275...0.3..0.151.552.1j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30.noJYy_lG7Ek&ved=0ahUKEwi6-Mnf9uXmAhXrm-AKHeRhA28Q4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Digital control:

Digital control is a branch of control theory that uses digital computers to act as system **controllers.** (Wikipedia)

[digital control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_control)

There is also: master/slave which some PC people do not like.
So, they suggest: worker and helper

[Python language](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/8x7akv/masterslave-terminology-was-removed-from-python-programming-language)

Here are more alternatives to master/slave:

Master-slave terminology alternatives
When you combine some of these various suggestions together, some fully formed master-slave terminology alternatives might include:

agency and operatives

captain and conscripts

**master and masons**

hive and drones

schemer and patsies

**primary and replicas**

scripture and prophets

[alternatives to master/slave](https://www.theserverside.com/opinion/Master-slave-terminology-alternatives-you-can-use-right-now)

Comment: In another part of my context, I'm using controller as another component of this system. This is why I prefer to choose another word in order to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Pablo You should have stated that at the beginning. Personally, I would not use any of the terms you ask about since they are people terms. There's always master/slave but you should read this: https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/8x7akv/masterslave-terminology-was-removed-from-python-programming-language So: workers and helpers....

Comment: "Master/slave" often has a specific meaning that is **not** implied with "parent/worker," etc, namely: the master device *dictates* exactly what the other devices do, and each slave device does exactly what every other slave device is doing, what with them all being slaved to the single master. "Leader/follower" and "primary/replica" are somewhat truer to reality but I personally feel like "master/slave" is overall the best and most accurate terminology. Not for @Pablo's situation here; I agree with you that "controller" is best, and if that's in use elsewhere that other usage should change...

Comment: In fact, considering the question further, the whole discussion about "master/slave" is entirely irrelevant, because Pablo is not talking about a master/slave setup. Still +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice among those you've suggested is **supervisor**.

An **observer** sounds like it would watch the other machine but not interact with it. The word **overseer** is less common in modern English and carries connotations of slavery; it should probably be avoided.

Comment: I have never seen that one computer supervises another.